# Done building project "D3D9 HOOK.vcxproj" -- FAILED

Tags: c++, windows

I want to build a program , but when click build solution it says :Done building project "D3D9 HOOK.vcxproj" -- FAILED

Here's My Code :

```
 #pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
 #pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
 #pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <Detours.h>
 #include <imgui.h>
 #include "imgui.h"
 #include "imgui_impl_dx9.h"
 #include "imgui_impl_win32.h"
 #include <d3d9.h>
 #include <d3dx9.h>



 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

PLease Help MEEEEE

Comment: I don't think anyone can help without the errors.

Comment: Why do you include `imgui.h` multiple times?

Comment: Output:C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\D3D9 HOOK\D3D9 HOOK\dllmain.cpp(25,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: the error: error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)